# How to convert Row to Column

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a tablix that Contains Type, Default, Break, CRG, Meeting, Training, Specialist, Personal, SpecialProjects and SystemOutage are arranged horizontally. I need to put it in a Pie Chart and each chart is filtered through dataset by Category.  The issue I am having is that Default, Break, CRG, Meeting, Training, Specialist, Personal, SpecialProjects and SystemOutage is in horizontal layout, and I need it to be in Vertical. I tried the Unpivot but I can't make it work with 9 fields. see below.

[image]

[image]
The expected result I need for a pie chart:

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for

```
Declare @YourTable table (Type varchar(50),[Default] int,[Break] int,CRG int,Meeting int,Training int,Specialist int,Personal int,SpecialProjects int,SystemOutage int)
Insert into @YourTable values
('Category1',32721,40634,0,1348,9162,0,10212,44549,17090),
('Category2',261997,83567,0,0,552312,0,17859,59345,30138)

Select B.*
 From  (Select Type,XMLData=cast((Select A.* for XML Raw) as xml) From @YourTable A) A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Type   = r.value('@Type','varchar(50)')
                      ,Item   = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value  = attr.value('.','int') 
                 From  XMLData.nodes('/row') as A(r)
                 Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr)
                 Where attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('Type')
             ) B
 Where A.Type='Category1'
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Thank you John. I re-evaluate my code and added the UNPIVOT and it works.

Comment: @Arsee The native UNPIVOT or this solution.  If native, it will be faster, it just requires you to define the fields.  I use this technique for a more dynamic approach.  If nothing else, keep this answer in your back pocket, I get a ton of use from it (being a lazy, lazy coder).  :)